# Backpropagation Derivation for CNNs

Tags: self-study, references, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I’m looking for a good reference (be that textbook, website, article…) that goes through a derivation of backpropagation in a multi-channel convolutional neural network. I’m also looking for a reference on how to vectorise the algorithm in this context too.